# VB asp.net to .net core

Tags: asp.net-core

I've a asp.net web application written in VB using Visual Studio 2013. Can I make it multiplatform using .net core? Should I get Visual Studio 2017 or can stay using 2013? thank you!

Comment: .Net Core will allow you to go cross platform and you will need VS2017 (or another environment like VS Code) but this question is not a good topic for Stack Overflow I'm afraid.

Comment: and you can use only C# or F#, but not VB

Answer (score 3):

Right now ASP.NET Core not available for VB.NET.

Please see [this forum](https://forums.asp.net/t/2119921.aspx?VB%20NET%20and%20NET%20Core):

> At the present time there is no firm or set time for this feature.
>
> It's planned and has been mentioned as being on the roadmap, but at
>   present it doesn't look like it can even be supported.

See [readmap](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/07/15/net-core-roadmap/).

You can use C# or F#.

And you need VS 2017 (or VS Code) for .NET Core.

Is it possible to use VS 2015 Update3, but not recommended, because they changed json project to MSBuild.

**UPDATE**: With [.NET Core 2 release](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/08/14/announcing-net-core-2-0/), now it's possible to use VB.NET in .NET Core, but not yet in ASP.NET:

[image]:

Comment: `It's planned and has been mentioned as being on the roadmap` oh dear.